# Key handling in Android

Tags: android, event-handling

Im trying to make a gane and i need to be able to move an object with the help of the key pad. 
I tried using the basic event handlers, like onKeyDown bit how do i redraw the screen??

Answer (score 0):

The screen is redrawn using the `invalidate()` function.